# 8u66 Windows 64-bit packager - install succeeds but application fails to start

Tags: javafx, window, bundle, packaging, java

My JavaFX Application is installed correctly in Windows 8 (64 bit) but refuses to run !

I use the JavaFX native packager to produce native install bundles for Windows (from an Eclipse / Ant script).

I create my Windows bundle from a 64-bit Windows 7 build machine - JDK used
: 8u66 b02 early access - 64-bit Windows.

Unfortunately there is no logs generated by Windows ! So it's difficult to know the cause of the crash.

For information this is the list of DLL installed :

MSVCP120.dll

MSVCR100.dll

MSVCR120.dll

My problem is similar to this issue (Java Bug system) : https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8131321

But this bug normally was fixed !

Any ideas ?

Comment: Did you try to run the jar file with a simple command line, or a batch script? That would at least throw you some errors and traces

Comment: Can you please add the content of the *.cfg file in you application directory? This is a typical place where things go wrong.

Comment: I found the problem - i had a bug in my ANT script (to build my application) : I pointed out 8u60 instead of 8u66 ("C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar" and "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\lib\ant-javafx.jar ") !

Comment: Except than 8u60 b25 (version used with my ANT script) does not have the hotfix on implementation problems in Windows 8/10 (bug fixed on 8u60 b26 and 8u66 b02). So, I builded again my application and I did the tests on Windows 8 / 10. No problem : the application installs and run correctly.